# Role to access url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I try to add role in a spring boot application who use springsecurity

In a class who extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

in the configure method, i have

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/report/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
http.csrf().disable();
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);   http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

I implemented UserDetailsService

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserApp userapp = repository.findByUsername(userName);

    if (userapp == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + userName + " not found");
    }

    return new CustomUserDetails(userapp);
    }
}


public class UserApp {
    ...
    ...
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleEnum role;
}

public enum RoleEnum {
    ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER;
}


public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final UserApp userApp;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        RoleEnum userRole = this.userApp.getRole();

        if (userRole != null) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.name());
            authorities.add(authority);
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

My user have ROLE_USER and can access to without problem to /report... it's not supposed to.

what is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/report/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
```

**Update: (Above answer did not work)**

Try below code

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/report/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
```

Comment: same issue, my user wit ROLE_USER cann access it.

Comment: just can't go with to my page with that... i get directly... There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Unauthorized... just not able to go to the login page...